# Leaflet - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I'm using this Leaflet Indoor Library (https://github.com/digitaltom/leaflet-indoor). I'm trying to change the level / floor names to 1F, 2F, 3F, etc. but I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
var indoor = new L.Indoor(geoJSON, {
    minCaptionZoom: 18,
    onEachFeature: roomCallBacks
});
indoor.addTo(map);

var levelControl = new L.Control.Level({
    level: "1F",
    levels: indoor.getLevels(),
    indoorLayer: indoor,
    parseLevel: function(level) {
    var levels = {
        "1F": 1,
        "2F": 2,
        "3F": 3
    };
    return levels[level];
  }
});
levelControl.addTo(map);
```

This is what GeoJSON looks like:

```
properties: {
    level: "1F",
    name: "Store",
},
```

The error is located here:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
at i.setLevel (leaflet-indoor.js:284:33)
at HTMLAnchorElement.levelBtn.onclick (leaflet-indoor.js:268:16)
```

The code for the leaflet-indoor.js is located in the link I've provided

Comment: What you call GeoJSON is only very small part of it. Please edit your question and add reproducible GeoJSON, together with coordinates.